# How many async/await is ok to spawn?

Tags: javascript, python, flutter, dart, asynchronous

I am fetching data from a server asynchronously. Now what I want to ask is how many async/await functions are ok to spawn. i.e
If I call 200 asynchronous functions in a for loop, and every async function make 100 requests to the server. is it efficient?
Here is some dummy code:

```
getData() async {
  for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    serverRequest();
  }
}

main() {
  for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    getData();
  }
}
```

What if I call the `getData()` a thousand times? I am using **Dart** language, but the question is applicable to all the async/await supported languages.

Comment: What is your metric for efficiency? When is a code efficient? Are you asking for opinions?

Comment: Theoretically, you can use as many as you want, it will not affect the code. It will effect performance and cost for every request to the server. It's upp to you.

Answer (score 2):

In Dart, async/await creates `Future`s (or `Stream`s if you use `async*`) which run within an isolate, which is single-threaded. You may think that they are async because they execute/complete in a random order, but in reality, all of your code runs synchronously inside of an event loop.

Don't worry and spawn as many as you want (within reason, you still can run out of memory and get `Stack Overflow` exception)